# Multicast detections problems

Tags: multicast

From a Windows 10 notebook, I would like to send the screen to a TV with Chromecast built-in. Except that the TV is not detected in device searches (screen or wireless docking station).
On the network, a Tplink ArcherC80 router:

- Igmp snooping=Enabled
- IGMP Proxy=Enabled
- No routing rules (chromecast) defined.
- All equipment on the same 2.4ghz wifi network.

Graphics card and network are compatible, AV + defender FW disabled.
I use Wireshark to analyze frames and yesterday only 4 Multicast packets were transmitted, today no Multicast requests are passing through Wireshark.
Why are Multicast requests interrupted?
Is a routing rule necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the router (its AP part) has client isolation enabled? (Assuming it has support for such feature.)

Comment: Is "Isolation AP" ? in Wifi\Additional parameters\Isolation Ap=Disable

Comment: Just in case, could you be mixing up Miracast and Chromecast?

Comment: However, "Miracast" or screen mirroring does not work until it detects the built-in Chromecast TV.

Comment: Not sure what you mean to be honest. Miracast (probably what "screen mirroring" refers to) has nothing to do with Chromecast. It makes use of WiFi Direct, which has nothing to do with your router. Your TV (or whatever device that connected to its HDMI port and serves as a receiver) needs to support Miracast for it to work. Its support for Chromecast will only allows you to cast from Chromecast supporting app/program.